# Resizing the Accordion with Selenium Junit

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, junit

While Trying to Resize the Accordion with the Selenium Java Code for the Demo Website http://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/accordion-and-tabs/

In **Re-Size Accordion** Tab

The Given HTML Code is

```
<body>
<h3 class="docs">Resize the outer container:</h3>
<div id="accordion-resizer" class="ui-widget-content ui-resizable">
<div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" role="tablist">
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-1" aria-controls="ui-id-2" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>Section 1</h3>
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-accordion-content-active" id="ui-id-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; height: 28px; overflow: auto;">
<p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
</div>
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-corner-top ui-accordion-header-collapsed ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-3" aria-controls="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Section 2</h3>
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; height: 28px; overflow: auto;">
<p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
</div>
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-corner-top ui-accordion-header-collapsed ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-5" aria-controls="ui-id-6" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Section 3</h3>
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-6" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; height: 28px; overflow: auto;">
<p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
<ul>
<li>List item one</li>
<li>List item two</li>
<li>List item three</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-corner-top ui-accordion-header-collapsed ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-7" aria-controls="ui-id-8" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Section 4</h3>
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-8" aria-labelledby="ui-id-7" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; height: 28px; overflow: auto;">
<p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div></div>
<div class="demo-description">
</div>


</body>
```

And The Java Code Written to Resize the Element is given below

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/accordion-and-tabs/");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement tab1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Simple Accordion']"));
    WebElement tab2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Re-Size Accordion']"));
    WebElement tab3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Toggle Icons']"));

    tab1.click();
    String var = tab1.getAttribute("class");
    System.out.println("The Class Attribute for First Tab:: " + var);
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    WebElement lists = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='post-2654']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p/iframe"));
    lists.click();
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".demo-frame")));
    List<WebElement> expandableLists = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".ui-accordion-header"));
    System.out.println("Lists Size:: "+expandableLists.size());

    WebElement element = expandableLists.get(2);
    new Actions(driver).click(element).build().perform();

    //WebElement sectionContent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-6']/p"));
    WebElement sectionContent = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-accordion-content[id = ui-id-6]"));
    //WebElement sectionContent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[3]/p"));

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    String ssTxt = sectionContent.findElement(By.tagName("p")).getText();
    //String s[] = ssTxt.split(",");
    System.out.println("The Content is:: "+ssTxt);

    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Strings after Split---> "+ s[i]);
    }
    */
    String ssTxt1 = sectionContent.findElement(By.tagName("ul")).getText();
    System.out.println("The Points of the Descr is: "+ssTxt1);
    String ss[] = ssTxt1.split("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("After Splitting ss: "+ss[i]);
    }
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-100)", "");
    tab2.click();

    WebElement vContainer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='post-2654']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/p"));
    //WebElement iFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".demo-frame"));

    String chck = vContainer.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")).getAttribute("src").toString();
    System.out.println("Just to Check the Source: "+chck);

    WebElement iFrame = vContainer.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));

    String s1 = iFrame.getAttribute("width").toString();
    System.out.println("Just to check inside IFrame: "+s1);

    driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);
    WebElement accordionResizer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='accordion-resizer']"));
    String s2 = accordionResizer.getAttribute("id").toString();
    //String s2 = iFrame.findElement(By.tagName("div")).getAttribute("id").toString();
    System.out.println("Check for Accordion: "+s2);

    String sSize = accordionResizer.getAttribute("style").toString();
    System.out.println("The Size of the Element is (accordionResizer):: "+ sSize);      
    WebElement accordianContainer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='accordion']"));
    String s3 = accordianContainer.getAttribute("class").toString();
    System.out.println("The Container accordian: "+s3);

    //driver.switchTo().frame(accordionResizer);
    //Creating a Web element for the Accordion resizable handler
    WebElement resizableElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='accordion-resizer']/div[4]"));
    String s4 = resizableElement.getAttribute("class").toString();
    System.out.println("The Resizable Handler: "+s4);

    int x = resizableElement.getSize().height;
    int y = resizableElement.getSize().width;

    System.out.println("The Size of the Frame:: "+ x  + " The Width: "+ y);

    //WebElement eWidthResizable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='accordion-resizer']/div[3]"));

    Actions act = new Actions(driver);

    //act.moveToElement(resizableElement).dragAndDropBy(resizableElement, 400,400).build().perform();
    act.moveToElement(resizableElement);
    act.clickAndHold();
    act.moveByOffset(400, 400);
    act.release();
    act.perform();

    driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
    System.out.println("End of All");
}
```

But While the Re sizable Element is clicked and hold through the code but the problem is that the cursor is still moving after the script has stopped and due to the movement of cursor manually the accordion is still getting resized.

Kindly someone help me with this so that the Accordion is Resized and the cursor is released after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to understand that the accordion control is placed in different frame so first we have to goto that frame:

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Eclipse\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");

  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

  driver.manage().window().maximize();


  driver.get("http://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/accordion-and-tabs/#Re-Size Accordion");

  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  Thread.sleep(10000);


 /* //Goto header frame

  WebElement headerFrame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/iframe"));

  driver.switchTo().frame(headerFrame);




  //click close icon on header frame

  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='close-icon']")).click();

  //Switch back to initial frame
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  */


  //Switch to new frame containing Accordion controls
  WebElement myFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#post-2654 > div.twelve.columns > div.newtabs.horizontal > div > div.single_tab_div.resp-tab-content.resp-tab-content-active > p:nth-child(2) > iframe"));

  driver.switchTo().frame(myFrame);

  Actions action = new Actions(driver);


  //element to be streched
  WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#accordion+div"));


  System.out.println(from.getText());

  Thread.sleep(10000);
  action.clickAndHold(from).moveByOffset(50,10).release(from).build().perform();

  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

  js.executeScript("document.getElementById('accordion-resizer').setAttribute('style', 'width: 700px; height: 400px;')");
```

Commented block of code is required if you see "element not clickable at this time" exception.